Associate unique identifier with rust function definitions
I have a struct that I would like to serialize to disk as part of a JSON save file format. The (simplified) structure of the struct is like this:
pub struct Effect {
  pub source: Source,
  pub duration: Duration,
  pub implementation: fn(&mut GameState, Source) -> Result<()>
}

I would like to serialize this structure via serde. Serializing function pointers is not possible, of course, so what I want to do is annotate each function I use as an implementation with a unique ID, write that ID as part of the saved JSON, and then use the ID to look up the function pointer to use when deserializing the structure, probably by building up a big map of functionId->functionPointer as a fist step. Is there a nice way for me to tag function definitions with this kind of metadata?
(note: I'm aware that I could convert Effect to a trait, but I really want to use function pointers here for a bunch of reasons -- ergonomics, performance, lots of existing code depending on this structure, etc)

The only way I can think of to make this work without major changes is to make this function compute its own serialization. For example, it could return an ID instead of (), and the serialization can call it with a dummy GameState and Source in order to get it. For deserialization, you would still need to manually enumerate all the functions that you plan on using. If I were to make this from scratch, I'd use an enum with a bunch of unit variants instead of a function pointer.

It's easy to build the mapping fnId->fnPtr, at least manually, but generally it is impossible to build the reverse mapping, since the same function may have multiple addresses. So the only viable way is as @drewtato said, to somehow encode the id in the function code itself. That can be by return type, or it can be via more exotic ways such as interpreting the function machine code with some known prefix.

Function pointers point directly to machine code. There is no way to attach additional metadata to them. You cannot compare the function pointers, either: you may experience both false negatives (functions which happened to be compiled twice) and false positives (functions whose machine code was deduplicated with another function that happens to have identical code).
The only way you can possibly get reliable information about a function pointer is to call it and see what it does. But at that point, you might as well use a trait object instead, rather than getting fancy with the function signature. The trait object can have a method for doing the operation and a method for asking for its ID in the serialization table.

Alternatively, if you have to build a table anyway, and all possible options are known at compile time, an enum would also be appropriate.

fair, the only other reasonable solution is probably some kind of 'fat pointer' scheme where each function pointer also carries an identifier for serialization and implements the Fn trait, but assigning such an identifier automatically would be really hard (you'd need to maybe somehow generate a custom const POINTER for every function with its pointer? and use that everywhere instead of the original pointer?)
